# osm2pgsql import fails with "Failed to read from node cache: Input/output error"

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis, mount, osm2pgsql

I'm attempting a whole-planet OSM data import on an AWS EC2. During or possibly after the "Ways" processing i receive the following message:

`"Failed to read from node cache: Input/output error"`

The EC2 has the following specs:

type: i3.xlarge
memory: 30.5 Gb
vCPUs: 4
Postgresql: v9.5.6
PostGIS: 2.2

In addition to the root volume, I have mounted 900GB SSD and a 2TB HHD (high throughput).  The Postgresql data directory is on the HHD.  I have commanded the `osm2pgsql` to write the flat-nodes file the SSD.

Here is my `osm2pgsql` command:

`osm2pgsql -c -d gis --number-processes 4 --slim -C 20000 --flat-nodes /data-cache/flat-node-cache/flat.nodes /data-postgres/planet-latest.osm.pbf`

I run the above command as user `renderaccount` that is a member of the following groups `renderaccount ubuntu postgres`. The `flat-nodes` file appears to be successfully created at `/data-cache/flat-node-cache/flat.nodes` and has this profile:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-230:/data-cache/flat-node-cache$ ls -l
total 37281800
-rw------- 1 renderaccount renderaccount 38176555024 Apr 13 05:45 flat.nodes
```

Has anyone run into and or resolved this?  I suspect maybe a permissions issue?  I notice now that since this last osm2pgsql failure, the mounted SSD that is the destination of the `flat-nodes` file has been converted to a "read-only" file system - which sounds like may happen when there are i/o errors on the mounted volume(?).

Also, does osm2pgsql write to a log that I could acquire additional info?

**UPDATE**: `dmesg` output:

```
[ 6206.884412] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme0n1, sector 66250752
[ 6206.890813] EXT4-fs warning (device nvme0n1): ext4_end_bio:329: I/O error -5 writing to inode 14024706 (offset 10871640064 size 8388608 starting block 8281600)
[ 6206.890817] Buffer I/O error on device nvme0n1, logical block 8281344
```

After researching the above output, it appears it might be a bug in Ubuntu 16.04. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1668129?comments=all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an error with Ubuntu 16.04 writing to the volume `nvme0n1`. Solved by this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1668129/comments/29